# Running a remote shell program with fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am just trying to run a shell program (`sudo('supervisorctl')` ) in fabric on a remote server without the `[host asdf] out:` stuff.

I can do `open_shell("sudo supervisorctrl")` but that gives me the motd and the rest of the shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `settings` [context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/context_managers.html) with `hide`:

```
from fabric.api import task, settings, hide

@task
def whatevs():
    with settings(hide('commands')):
        sudo('sudo supervisorctl')
```

There is more info about the "output levels" that hide can take [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/output_controls.html).